# Using the Mean Value Theorem to show Continuity

Tags: calculus

[image]

I do not understand how you can use the MVT to show the continuity.

Answer (score 1):

We need to show: $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = f(0) = \displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{-}} f(x)$.

For the left equation, we have: for $x > 0$, $f(x) - f(0) = \dfrac{e^x-1}{x} - 1 = \dfrac{e^x-1-x}{x} = e^{\xi} - 1$, $\xi \in (0,x)$. Thus:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{\xi \to 0^{+}} e^{\xi} = 1 = f(0)$.

Similarly, $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0^{-}} f(x) = \displaystyle \lim_{\xi \to 0^{-}} e^{\xi} = 1 = f(0)$.

we conclude that $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$.